# What characters can I use in a Git alias?

Tags: git, alias

What characters can I use in a Git alias? For example can "my.branch" or "@mine" be aliases?

Is there a way to make the aliases case sensitive? ex: my**B**ranch

The [alias documentaion](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases) does not list acceptable characters or anything about case sensitivity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [git-config man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

> The variable names are case-insensitive, allow only alphanumeric
> characters and -, and must start with an alphabetic character

Git aliases are variables in the git config options (e.g. in the `.gitconfig` file).

So, git aliases are case-insensitive, and neither "my.branch" nor "@mine" can be aliases.

Comment: That's too bad. I have `a` aliased to `add`. Sometimes when I try to type `git a .` I typo it as `git a.`. Git tells me that command doesn't exist and continues under the assumption that I meant `am`, which puts me in rebasing mode. :( I would like to alias `a.` to `a .`, but it looks like I can't.

Answer (score 3):

[`man git-config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) says:

> The variable names are case-insensitive, allow only alphanumeric characters and -, and must start with an alphabetic character.

For those who want to use a dot (`.`) as part of the variable name, the same man page also says:

> The variables are divided into sections, wherein the fully qualified variable name of the variable itself is the last dot-separated segment and the section name is everything before the last dot.

This should make it clear why those people (including me) are out of hope.