# Git alias to delete branch has no warning

Tags: git, branch

When trying to delete a git branch that has not been merged, such as `git branch -d my-feature`, I would get a warning

```
error: The branch 'my-feature' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D my-feature'.
```

However, when I have a git alias in my `~/.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
    bd = branch -d
```

and then do `git bd my-feature`, git has no problem deleting the branch without a warning.

Is this the expected behavior? Does it have anything to do with the use of the alias?

Comment: I guess your question is based on a wrong assumption, and most likely you missed that the branch, you've deleted with success, was already _present_ in the history of the current HEAD and then you simply executed `git bd my-feature` (or you accidentally added the `-f` flag when executed the aliased command). I do believe aliases cannot affect git behavior especially for extremely simple cases like this one.

Comment: I thought so too, so I created new branches to test. The same behavior still applies. I also checked the alias for `-f`, but don't see anything.

Comment: Are you sure that the branch being deleted points a commit _ahead_ of the upstream branch you're at (or these two branches make diverged commits) when running the alias? I just created a new repo with the master branch by adding a dummy file, then I created a branch `my-feature` off the master branch, created a new commit for the latter branch, git-config-ed the local repository alias with `git config alias.bd 'branch -d'`, checked out back to master, and `git bd my-feature` failed as expected. Can you provide the git log graph and tell where your HEAD points at when running the alias?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], because I don't believe this actually happens.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the cause of my problem. In the list of git aliases, in addition to `bd = branch -d`, some lines further down I had inadvertently included `bD = branch -D`, which force-delete the branch. I guess **git aliases are case-insensitive**, so it matches the second alias instead of the first.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16821201/1126841.

Comment: Yes I saw that after I figured out what the problem was.